# Cannot install new omega driver from AMD

Tags: 14.04, package-management, ati, gpu-driver

Hi all I'm trying to install the new omega drivers for Ubuntu 14.04

AMD Catalyst™ 14.12

But the ubuntu software center is complaining "Dependency is not satisfiable: fglrx-core"

I'm downloading this package.

http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/fglrx_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb

Comment: You need to download multiple deb packages from AMD's site.

Comment: So basically all packes that have 14.04 in them? Also which one do I install first?

Comment: You probably need to install them at the same time. AMD should provide instructions on how to install them. You probably don't need all the packages, but you will need most of them. You can download them to a directory and then run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` in that directory to install them.

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/a/568524/178596

Answer (score 4):

I had the same result, but I got it to work. Instead of the Ubuntu packages, get the generic "Linux (32-bit & 64-bit)" which is 148 MB zip file. Unzip and then `sudo ./amd-driver-installer-14.501.1003-x86.x86_64.run`.  Choose to build packages for Trusty.  It takes several minutes and doesn't seem to be doing anything, but just wait for it.

Then when I tried `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` with the resulting files it told me there was a conflict so I had to do `apt-get remove ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64` before it would work. But then the 4 .deb files installed without error.

---

```
sudo aticonfig --initial and reboot. flgrxinfo now reports:
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13283 Compatibility Profile Context 14.501.1003
```

Seems to work but the catalyst control center won't start.

Edit: I tried Counter Strike in Steam and it ran very smooth. Much better than before but I think I had a broken driver install before.

Edit2: My chrome://gpu/ used to show all red / disabled and now only "Multiple Raster Threads" is disabled. Everything else is green. Full screen 60fps youtube is buttery smooth with no tearing.

Edit3: download separate amdcccle.deb package from amd site and reinstall it with Gdebi or Software centre, then Catalyst Control Cetntre will start.

Answer (score 3):

fglrx-core seems to be the named "minimal driver" on amd website's page for ubuntu_64Bit, and here's the download link (accessible on December 31,2014):

Direct link (for ubuntu 14.04 64bit):
http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb

Download page:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064

Comment: AMD does not seem to allow direct external links: `You were linked to this download from a site outside of AMD.com`