# Installation of newest AMD drivers fails

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I'm trying to update my drivers to the latest version provided by AMD. I couldn't find a way to simply update them, so I decided to uninstall them completely by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
```

Then I rebooted, and ran:

```
./amd-driver-installer-14.501.1003-x86.x86_64.run
```

The installer generated the package and I installed it. I then tried to run

```
aticonfig --initial
```

but I get the error:

```
Unable to open /etc/ati/control, please reinstall the driver.
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

Thinking the installation messed up, I uninstalled the drivers again, rebooted, and tried to install once more. I get the same error. How can I successfully install the drivers?

Comment: Why do you need ATI's proprietary driver? Was there something wrong with the open source one?

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste Yes, for example, OpenGL4 support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable support for 32bit packages if you have a 64bit OS -

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Install the following packages -

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
```

---

Install all the dependencies listed on [this page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalystOmegaLINReleaseNotes.aspx).

Download all the `.deb` files related to Ubuntu 14.04 (`fglrx`,`fglrx-core`,`fglrx-dev` and `fglrx-amdcccle`) from [this page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064).

Copy the downloaded `.deb` files to a folder.

Now, open a Terminal and `cd` to the created folder -

```
cd /path/to/folder
```

Install the `.deb` files using `dpkg` -

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: If you try to install the deb files, you will encounter errors due to missing dependencies. You can either install these packages using the commands given or try to use the `-f` argument with `apt-get install` to force install the missing dependencies.

Comment: The downloads page (link provided) also explicitly mentions that 32bit packages must be installed for 64bit drivers to install or work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I managed to install it all seamlessly using this method as well. I decided to install the dependencies myself following the erros outputed, but interestingly I didn't have to, the only package required by the installation was dkms, and all installed fine after installing it.

Answer (score 2):

I have Successfully installed AMD OMEGA Driver by following these steps :

Note: If you previously tried to install any openGL driver "fglrx" purge , autoremove . then reboot your system.

Now follow the steps which i have done to successfully install amd omega driver .

```
sudo apt-get update
```

finish the **software updater pending list** . go to Settings then goto **Language and Support** if updates there install it . Then click **"Apply Syststem wide"**

Then
    sudo apt-get install gksu

Get the amd omega driver for linux from official amd site [get amd driver here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64)

after getting amd-catalyst-omega-14.12-linux-run-installers.zip , unzip it

let me consider that file located in Downloads

```
cd Downloads/

unzip amd-catalyst-omega-14.12-linux-run-installers.zip 

cd fglrx-14.501.1003/

sudo chmod +x amd-driver-installer-14.501.1003-x86.x86_64.run 

./amd-driver-installer-14.501.1003-x86.x86_64.run
```

The last action shows some dependency requirement error in /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log

**NOTE**

Even after error AMD Driver Proceed to Install don't do it cancel it .

read the error and then follow the steps given there

```
cat /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log
```

For me the dependency error showed me to in install the following components

```
sudo apt-get install debhelper

sudo apt-get install dh-modaliases

sudo apt-get install execstack

apt-get install dpkg-dev

sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev

sudo apt-get install dkms

sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

After installing these Dependency Packages run

```
./amd-driver-installer-14.501.1003-x86.x86_64.run
```

it will then follows next next installation , Be patient until it build packages and it install it automatically .

After installation Succesful

```
sudo reboot
```

To check whether the installation is Success or not run the following cmds in terminal

```
fglrxinfo
```

to Enable AMD Radeon DPM (Dynamic Power Management) Run the Following Cmds

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1"`

```
sudo update-grub
```

Some Tweaks Regarding Brightness Getting Reset Fix (Optional) Read this [Fix Brightness Getting Reset (To A Very Low Value Or Maximum) On Reboot In Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/fix-brightness-getting-reset-to-very.html)

For Power Management Consider installing this TLP and Laptop Mode