# fglrx drivers for Ubuntu 20: error version '-' has bad syntax

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, fglrx, gpu-driver

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a radeon hd 5830 GPU (I know, it's old). The open source radeon driver is working fine for regular office/web use but it looks like I need the proprietary drivers for gaming. I'm aware of similar threads [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863547/not-able-to-install-amd-fglrx-driver-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568443/installation-of-newest-amd-drivers-fails), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254156/ati-mobility-radeon-hd-5450-ubuntu-20-04), but I'm not sure they apply to my situation, or aren't answered.

The official fglrx drivers listed [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/ati-radeon-hd-5000-series/ati-radeon-hd-5830) only go up to Ubuntu 14.04. But the documentation seems to suggest they should work with newer versions, too. Searches for radeon and Ubuntu 20.04 or 18.04 lead to drivers that don't seem to be compatible with my hardware, like [amdgpu-pro](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20). There are 4 .deb files for the fglrx drivers. Starting with the "core" file (if I try to install the other 3 first they each throw dependency errors asking for fglrx-core), I get:

```
sudo apt install ./fglrx-core_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'fglrx-core' instead of './fglrx-core_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms lib32gcc1
Suggested packages:
  menu
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms fglrx-core lib32gcc1
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/82.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 238 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 /home/user/Downloads/fglrx-core_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb fglrx-core amd64 2:15.201-0ubuntu1 [82.8 MB]
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 203959 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.8.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32gcc1.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32gcc1_1%3a10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32gcc1 (1:10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-core.
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx-core_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-core (2:15.201-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up lib32gcc1 (1:10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fglrx-core (2:15.201-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx-core/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GFXCORE.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxc
ore_conf) in auto mode
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
Loading new fglrx-core-15.201 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-54-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-54-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/fglrx-core.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-54-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/15.201/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fglrx-core (--configure):
 installed fglrx-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then end up in some kind of broken state and have to do `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-core` and `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up. I also tried the generic linux driver listed on the same radeon 5830 page:

```
./AMD-Catalyst-15.9-Linux-installer-15.201.1151-x86.x86_64.run 
Created directory fglrx-install.cO4xT2
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-15.201.1151......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer _64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib32:XServer _64a:none:5.4.0-54-generic:)
Installation will not proceed.

Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.cO4xT2
```

I would understand if there's really no way to get a proprietary driver for my GPU working on Ubuntu 20.04, but I want to be certain about that before I give up.

Comment: Since 2016, Ubuntu has had specialist *yy* releases such as Ubuntu Core 16, Ubuntu Core 18 etc.  These are *snap* only systems, and won't use all *deb* files designed for the standard *yy.mm* releases of Ubuntu.  You mention 14.04, but also mention various *snap* only builds (18, 20) and a 20.04. Please be specific with your release details, and clarify your question; as *yy* releases are different products to the standard desktop/server builds using *yy.mm* format.

Comment: Please refer to valid Ubuntu releases. Ubuntu has both *yy* and *yy.mm* releases which are different products, with different capabilities and intended audiences. Ubuntu releases with *yy* are less flexible, but that's also of benefit as they are smaller making them ideal for appliances, devices & cloud use.  You reference both even after edit  (remove them & I can remove my comments)